# Alinhamento quebrado com Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Olá,

Estou fazendo a seguinte página.

http://www.goldhairmoveis.com.br/bancos

E por algum motivo o alinhamento ficou errado no quarto produto.

Já inspecionei tudo e aparentemente não tem nenhum erro ou diferença entre as divs.

Alguém faz alguma ideia?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

É porque o segundo item possui 263px de altura, enquanto que o primeiro e o terceiro possuem ~262px.

Provavelmente você esta calculando as alturas através de algum Javascript [direta ou indiretamente]. Fixe as alturas (por exemplo em 263px) que o problema era desaparecer.

Ou fixe as alturas dos produtos em cada linha no valor que melhor se ajuste aos seus produtos. Inclusive, o ideal alí seria utilizar thumbnails.